# How to make one Ember data model fits for multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have to handle something HTTP methods from external api (create and update) by DS.store. Server expects other fields for create method, than for update method. For example:

Expected params for POST in json:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "login": "string",
  "password": "string",
}
```

Expected params for PUT method:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "subdomain": "string",
  "person": "string",
}
```

Obviously, i have other forms for these actions, but DS.store takes all fields from DS.model for request. My model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  login: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  subdomain: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  person: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

So, for example, POST request looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "somethingName",
  "email": "something@something.fuu",
  "login": "login",
  "password": "passw",
  "subdomain": null,
  "person": null
}
```

Even, if not expected keys have null or undefined value, my server returns 400 ( unrecognized parameters "subdomian", "person").
Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server, so I have to pass to the server only expected params. I tried also something like this in serializer:

```
attrs: {
        person: { serialize: false },
        subdomain: { serialize: false },
}
```

But naturally it was creating errors for PUT request...
Is there something way to pass only params included in my html form, or delete params, which have null/undefined value before request to the server? I know, I can use something other than DS.store, but I want to have clear code with only one middleman between client and server.

Comment: have to try to make your own adapter?

Comment: Thanks, i created new adapter, and changed ajax method.

Comment: I had made it a answer so other have similiar issue can refer the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ember Data, the Adapter determines how data is persisted to a backend data store, such as the URL format and headers for a REST API.

If you have one model that has exceptional rules for communicating with its backend than the others you can create a Model specific Adapter by running the command

```
ember generate adapter adapter-name
```

For more information about customizing your adapter read the link below,

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/models/customizing-adapters/